# Оглушается ли согласная?

Tags: нормы-языка

Как правильно ГОВОРИТЬ:"ЛеониТ Алексеевич" или "ЛеониД Алексеевич"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При произношении оба слова сливаются, поэтому согласный "д" в данном случае не оглушается, так как стоит перед гласным "А". Если же имя произносится отдельно, то, естественно, оно звучит как "Лианит"

Comment: Считаю, ответ неверный. Аргументы в моём ответе.

Comment: Ответ верный в первом приближении. Если у чему и придираться, так к некоторой шероховатости формулировок, никак не к сути.

Академические заморочки по вашим ссылкам - это уже высшая математика. Если вообще имеет место что-то подобное, позже посмотрю.

Comment: На самом деле всё достаточно просто. Послушайте песню "Снег идёт" (например: http://ir2.ru/img/snegidet.WAV). Никаких заморочек.

Answer (score 1):

В быстрой речи слова обычно произносятся без пауз, если иное не вызвано интонацией или грамматикой. Поэтому Д перед гласной не оглушается.
Но если произнесение подчеркнуто медленное (для лучшего восприятия или, например, слушающий записывает), то Д переходит в Т по обычным правилам.

Comment: Зачем повторять, если ответ есть, практически такой же ?

Comment: Чтобы Вы могли об этом спросить.

Comment: Надо поощрять активность членов форума, даже если ответы близки. Идентичными они вряд ли могут быть (кстати: "вряд ли" = "едва ли"?)

Comment: Да дело не в этом. Меня поощрять не надо.
Просто кое-кто не заметил весьма существенный момент в моем ответе.  
По Виктору получается, что выбор варианта произношения остаётся за говорящим. Захотел - слитно произнес, захотел раздельно. Это не так.
А ответы, кстати, шли почти одновременно, я когда писал свой, прочитать предыдщий не мог.

Comment: @tmp, математика тут не особо высшая (подумаешь, бином Ньютона! :-)). На стыках **разных морфем** происходит уподобление согласных **в разной степени** - для этого, в частности, и ввели пониятие "диэрема".

Answer (score 0):

Ответ здесь совершенно не очевиден. И его вообще невозможно корректно дать без учёта понятия **диэрема**:

> ...фонетические показатели границ
> фонетических слов (а также и других
> фонетических и нефонетических единиц –
> морфем, лексических слов, синтагм) в
> современном русском языке выражены
> достаточно ярко. Комплексы таких
> показателей называются диэремами или
> пограничными сигналами. Теория
> пограничных сигналов была предложена
> Н.С.Трубецким и разработана
> М.В.Пановым
>
> [...]
>
> Перечислим теперь некоторые показатели
> границ, из которых могут состоять
> диэремы.
>
> [...]
>
> 2 Оглушение звонких шумных согласных происходит в конце синтагмы ([друк#0]
> – друг), фонетического слова (если
> дальше не следует звонкий шумный:
> [дрýк#1л'ены] – друг Лены) или
> знаменательного слова перед служебным
> ([дрýк#2л'и óн] – друг ли он?). Этот
> показатель отсутствует у #4 и #3.

[Суперсегментная фонетика](http://www.philol.msu.ru/~ruslang/data/pdf/4.pdf)

Звук А не является звонким шумным, следовательно перед ним на границе синтагмы должно происходить оглушение звонкого согласного.

---

Пример из живой речи - песня "Снег идёт". Там нет никакого "снеГЫдёт", послушайте: http://ir2.ru/img/snegidet.WAV

Comment: А если "И": Леонид Ильич? "Т" или "Д"? Какие гласные являются звонкими шумными?.. Это очень интересно!.. Русисты, пожалуйста, не будьте ревнивы друг к другу. Абсолютных истин всё равно нет. Есть обмен мнениями, и он очень интересен для неспециалистов, тех, кто любит русский язык, хотя, может быть, занимается профессионально чем-то другим. Нередко бывает: женился человек, а первую любовь помнит всю свою жизнь. Вспомните свою молодость. Хотя, впрочем, это отношения к теме не имеет: прошу прощения.

Comment: Пыталась прислушаться к себе, и ничего не поняла: получается то так, то так. Чистота эксперимента нарушена. Надо бы услышать сочетание со стороны, от "неподготовленного"  человека.

Comment: >А если "И": Леонид Ильич?  
А если И то оно переходит в Ы: "Леонидылич"[л'иън'идыл'(йи/ы)ч']. Как-то так.

Comment: Я тоже пыталась уловить в своем произношении. Скорее все-таки Т в любом случае - и Ильич, и Алексеевич. Но у кого-то, допускаю, получится по-другому. У меня есть склонность к редуцированию гласных в принципе. Получается как-то [лианитйлич] и [лианитъликсеич].

Comment: @DocentI, сейчас @tmp этим заняться некогда :-), ну, поставьте эксперимент самостоятельно. Это ведь очень просто. Надо подобрать (*подбросить*) несколько похожих сочетаний с разной степенью "разности": например, со служебными частями речи и с "полноценными". Как-то так:

ПоД зонтиком
ходиТ Зощенко

В первой строке и во второй - неужели все слышат одинаковое уподобление? По законам русской фонетики и Д, и Т здесь должны переходить в звонкое Ц. 

---------------

На стыках разных морфем происходит уподобление согласных **в разной степени**.

Comment: Я никак не возьму в толк, с кем и о чем спорит @stopkran. 
По его ссылке - некое академическое обсуждение теорири слогоделения...
Где там что-то насчет регрессирующей ассимиляции *аллофонов* на стыках слов?! К нашему практическому вопросу это, похоже, никак не относится. 
ЗЫ Песня - не аргумент. Тем более, что случай стыка Г/К/Х с И  - вообще особый, там форсированая пауза по фонетическим причинам: заднеязычные не ассимилируются в сторону мягкости, а сочетание ГЫ нехарактерно для русского. Поэтому произношение там сильно варьируется у различных носителей. Возможно что-то типа "снег-йидёт"

Comment: Не нравится песня? Произношение Никитина не авторитетно? Ну, вот вам Сергей Юрский: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SC7eecof4-U

ЗЫ. Слава богу, хоть один *особый случай* на стыке морфем позволили Трубецкому с Пановым на Хэшкоде...

Comment: stopkran, не трудитесь. Я вообще не слушаю ничего по Вашим ссылкам. 
Не мой стиль спора, субъективно все, да и звук на компе обычно не включаю.  
Я говорил о том, что произношение любого исполнителя песен - и стихов, кстати, тоже - изначально не аргумент по вопросу норм обычной орфоэпии. Там свои законы. 

>К нашему ... вопросу... Приведите хотя бы один.
   
После Вас. Я вообще перестал понимать, о каком вопросе Вы говорите. Я о том, что в теме обозначен. Сформулируйте, что именно вы собираетесь доказать  - и на каком основании. Проще будет.  
А вопрос об "авторитетах" мы пока оставим.

Comment: @tmp, я тружусь не для вас лично (ничего личного! только бизнес!)

Я защищаю основной тезис своего ответа: произношение "Леонидылич" - неверно, согласная здесь оглушается из-за **диэремы**.

Московское театральное произношение является эталоном в установлении орфоэпических норм, поэтому мои ссылки на речь Никитина, Юрского и Ахматовой - достаточно серьёзные аргументы. 

Я могу принять аргументы такого же плана (со ссылками на речь хотя бы Жванецкого или Александра Иванова). У вас этих аргументов нет, и вы их не хотите искать. В теорию вникать тоже не хотите: "Панова не читал, но мнение имею".